# How to save a SQLite binding into an NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have the following bind statement for binding an SQLite column. I want to save this value into an `NSString` named `journeyName`. For this I have written the following statement:

```
NSString * journeyName = sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, 
                                           [Gjourney UTF8String], -1, 
                                           SQLITE_TRANSIENT );
```

This gives me a warning that

> initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

and my app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    // Read the data from the result row
    NSString * journeyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
    NSLog(@"journeyName - %@",journeyName);
```

For Reference - [sample code](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess you should have written

`NSString* journeyName = sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [Gjourney UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);`

Comment: sorry typing mistake i have written NSString *journeyName

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as the following:

```
NSString *journeyName = sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [Gjourney UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

THis should work.

Comment: sorry it was a typing mistake i had written NSString *journeyName

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_bind_text` binds a text value to a SQL parameter **prior to executing the SQL statement**. This means that you are already in possession of the `NSString*` value that you are passing. The return value of `sqlite3_bind_text` is an `int` not `NSString*`.

If you mean that you want to the value that is returned to the SQL statement following executing it, then you need to look at [sqlite3_column_text](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html).

For example...

```
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    char *cstr = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0); // 0 = the param index
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstr];
}
```